# Parsing JSON from URL in android : always getting empty string as result. Any solutions please?

Tags: android, json

Here's my code I'm using to get json data (still working on little data to get to know json parsing but I get deprecated in httpClient, httpGet, httpResponseLine. I don't know what "deprecated" means either. So, could you please help me out in knowing what deprecated means and also look at the code that always comes up with empty string result?

```
private String getJsonData() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            result=builder.toString();
            return result;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {}


                return result;
}
```

Also rest of the code : calling part :

```
 String s = getJsonData();


String result,url="https://api.myjson.com/bins/51umq";
```

Thanks, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: first check that value of `url` variable in method `getJsonData()` and verify that its correct. another thing you are returning result twice. remove `return` statement inside try

Comment: and most imp...make sure you have added `INTERNET permission` in your `manifest`

Comment: Thanks for the answers, Karan. I've removed a `return` statement and also checked that the `url` variable exists with it's value in the `getJson()` function. But still the returned string is blank I have no idea whatsoever about why. `Internet permission` is added in `manifest` as well

Comment: Also if this is of any help, the code I've typed isn't in an activity but in a fragment.

Comment: you are doing network operation so first you need to have permission to do that

Comment: so add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` this line below <uses-sdk>

Comment: Thanks again, Karan. It's added. I'll try to debug and experiment on it for a while. I've gone wrong somewhere lol. It still returns a null string unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

As **HttpClient** got deprecated you should use **HttpUrlConnection** class getting json file from server.

```
public String getData(String url){
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            URL url1 = new URL(url.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url1
                    .openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream());

            int b;
            while ((b = in.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) b);
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working but pretty much same result in returned string. Any ideas on that? Also if this is of any help, the code I've typed isn't in an activity but in a fragment.

Comment: What is your concern can u explain.

Comment: The returned string always is `null`. I've tried to debug with breakpoint using your given code. It goes till the `InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());` and goes to `catch` that I've set after the `try` setting the returning string value as `null`

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.imagetalkies.www.imagetalkies" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >`

Comment: Continued :         
`<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use `deprecated` objects (function). Why? Because in the future, maybe your code will not work anymore (how long your code work is up to Google). AFAIK, you should use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/training/volley/simple.html) to handle Transmitting Network Data. It's recommended by Google Site:

> Volley is an HTTP library that makes networking for Android apps easier and most importantly, faster.

With simple request:

```
//Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";
// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
    mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
}
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
}
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

P/s: Dont forget to add [Volley Library](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) to your project

Comment: Thanks on that but I get "Cannot Resolve" for `RequestQueue`

Comment: @Rathan I add link above, check it.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am using LoopJ AsyncHttpClient http://loopj.com/android-async-http/..
For more elegant results, I would suggest http://square.github.io/retrofit/ so that you will have your Java Interface.

**In your "getJsonData()" you can place this code. Remember to add library in gradle build.**

```
  AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/51umq",new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("JSONObject", ":" + response);
                try{
                    JSONArray books = response.getJSONArray("book");
                    int length = books.length();
                    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
                        JSONObject content = books.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.d("Author",":" + content.getString("author"));
                    }
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                Log.d("onFailure", ":" + responseString);
            }
        });
```